# User defined Section Environment - Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: sectioning, environments, texmaker

I am trying to create a user defined environment to create a `section` the code for which is

```
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

After defining the environment I run the following code to create a section

```
\begin{document}

\begin{rSection}{Education}

{\bf Institute of Business Administration, Karachi} \hfill {\em July 2016 - May 2020} 
\\ BS Economics \& Mathematics \hfill { Overall CGPA: 3.03 }

\end{rSection}

\end{document}
```

The above code results in following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\rSection #1-> \sectionskip
\MakeUppercase {\bf #1} \sectionlineskip \hrule ...
l.32 \begin{rSection}{Education}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I am new to latex and can't get what is the issue?

My preamble is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The `\sectionskip` command that you use in the definition of your `rSection` environment is not defined anywhere by TeX, the LaTeX kernel, the document class and the packages that you have loaded. What makes you think that TeX knows what `\sectionskip` means? Also, please provide a minimal working example in one block, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`: this will make it much, much easier to help you.

Comment: @frougon you've correctly pointed out I need to define `\sectionskip`. I was following a tutorial so missed out that part. I defined both `\sectionskip` and `\sectionlineskip` and now the code is working.

Comment: note that `\bf` is not defined by latex either (it was removed in 1993)  `article` class adds a compatibility definition for documents from the 1980s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The error message:

```latex
! Undefined control sequence.
\rSection #1-> \sectionskip
\MakeUppercase {\bf #1} \sectionlineskip \hrule ...
l.32 \begin{rSection}{Education}
```

says that when expanding things from line 32 of the file being processed, TeX found `\sectionskip` from the expansion of macro `\rSection`, which itself comes from the expansion of `\begin{rSection}{Education}` according to your definition of the `rSection` environment:

```latex
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  ...
}
```

In order to fix this kind of error, one needs to make TeX know what `\sectionskip` means. In some cases, loading a particular package providing the missing command is enough. In your case, it is apparently a user command that you forgot to define.

Note: there is likely a spacing error here, you should remove the space before the percent sign, like this:

```latex
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{% <-- here
  \sectionskip
  ...
}
```

(although, if used in vertical mode, the space token won't do anything; but being strict is safer and doesn't cost anything, better play safe when you are beginning).

Comment: I added a note regarding a possible spurious space.